# How to save multiple buffers

Tags: buffers, saving

After modifying multiple files, how can I save all their buffers?

Comment: `multi-occur` is not dependent on projectile. It is a vanill Emacs command from standard library `replace.el`.  Why mention (and link to) projectile here? Is there really something pertinent about projectile in your question? Search and replace seem to be irrelevant to the question, as well.

Comment: `C-h a` (`apropos-command`) is your friend. `C-h a save buffers` tells you about commands whose names match `save` and `buffers`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that `multi-occur` is built in. I mentioned projectile specifically as it is a feature and package that people may not know about. Most folks are diligent at saving while editing, so the use case of updating multiple files at a time makes more sense within the context of a library like projectile and/or multi-occur. The same goes for using a macro to edit multiple buffers. My thought was that including these libs helps widen the discoverability of helpful features.

Answer (score 9):

After making the changes you can save the open buffers using `save-some-buffers`. This is bound `C-x s` by default.

Here is what the docs say.

```
Save some modified file-visiting buffers.  Asks user about each one. 
You can answer `y' to save, `n' not to save, `C-r' to look at the 
buffer in question with `view-buffer' before deciding or `d' to 
view the differences using `diff-buffer-with-file'.
```

You can use `C-u C-x s` to save without asking.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>M-x ibuffer * u S</kbd> is quite convenient for this as well, because you can add/remove selected buffers with `m` or `u` before saving with `S`.

Comment: Likwise, `buffer-menu`.